# Variable Scope of function inside function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery function extend, but the exec command for the redColorBtn does not seem to work. If I move the var iframeDocument definition to inside the redColorBtn function, then it works. But, I can't wrap my head around why this would happen. I thought it would be because of variable scope, but then the iframe definition should also not be working outside the redColorBtn click function. Does anyone know?

```
$.extend({
 handleToolbarEvents: function(iframeDocumentId) {
     var iframe          = document.getElementById(iframeDocumentId);
     var iframeDocument  = iframe.contentWindow.document;
     var redColorBtn     = document.getElementById('rte-redColorBtn-' + iframeDocumentId);

     $(redColorBtn).click(function() {
        var command = $(this).val();//foreColor
        iframeDocument.execCommand(command, false, "red");
     });

     $('.rte-button').click(function() {
        var command        = $(this).val();
        var iframeID       = $(this).closest('iframe[class="rte-iframe"]');
        var iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        iframeDocument.execCommand(command, null, null);
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? Are there errors, or what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

i have once's the same problem that i add the click event but it doesn't work. It can be about if you are adding that `redColorBtn` dynamically it might be your problem. you can try `redColorButton.bind('click', function(){});` I don't know why it but it worked for me.

Hope it works.